# Classifying Teams in Soccer

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-learn, k-means

I want to classify the teams in a soccer game.

What I tried is that I first detect players via the yolov3 model. Once I get the Bounding boxes for the player, I make a player crop which is basically the section of the image where the detected player is. I pass that sub-image of the player to a function `find_dominant_color(image)` which is supposed to return the most dominant color of that sub-image. For some reason, it's not working fine.

```py
def find_dominant_color(img):
    # average = img.mean(axis=0).mean(axis=0)
    pixels = np.float32(img.reshape(-1, 3))
    n_colors = 5
    # the final param is epsilon. It is the minimum amount the centroid has to move before the update is terminated
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 500, .05)
    flags = cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS
    #   Using kmeans to determine n_colors centroids from the complete set of pixel values
    _, labels, palette = cv2.kmeans(
        pixels, n_colors, None, criteria, 10, flags)
    _, counts = np.unique(labels, return_counts=True)
#     print(counts)
    dominant = np.int0(palette[np.argmax(counts)])
    return dominant
```

I expect this function to return a list of BGR value that represents some shade of Yellow color if the player is wearing a yellow jersey or some shade of white if the players are wearing a white jersey.